# How to make PHP not crop to the top left of my resizing?

Tags: php

I am resizing an image (for a user's profile icon) to a 200x200 size with PHP so I don't cram my page with a huge image. However, my code seems to crop to remove anything that's not in the top left part of the image if it is not a square. How do I have it just resize normally to 200x200? Here's my code:

```
    <?php

//Function that will create a thumbnail of images submitted
function createThumbnail($image_name, $thumbnail_name, $size, $type) {

                //creates the image based on the type of file
                if($type == "image/jpeg") {
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_name); 
                }
                else if ($type == "image/png") {
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_name);
                }
                else if ($type == "image/gif") {
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_name);
                }


                $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size); 


                // if height and width are not equal... 
                if(imagesx($image) > imagesy($image)){
                    imagecopyresized($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, imagesy($image), imagesy($image)); 
                }
                else {
                    imagecopyresized($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, imagesx($image), imagesx($image)); 
                }


                if($type == "image/jpeg") {
                    imagejpeg($thumbnail, $thumbnail_name, 100);  
                }
                else if ($type == "image/png") {
                    imagepng($thumbnail, $thumbnail_name, 0); 
                }
                else if ($type == "image/gif") {
                    imagegif($thumbnail, $thumbnail_name); 
                }
}
    ?>
```

Thanks guys!
-Adam

Comment: You can refer to this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: I'm assuming by "resize normally" you just want to resize and not crop the image (ie you have an image that is 400x800 it would become 100x200) ?

Comment: I was going to point him toward that documentation too, but I noticed that that page says "If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed." But he is saying that it appears to be cropping the image instead of resizing it.

Comment: Yes that's correct CMorrissey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the image size data

```
$imageData = @getimagesize($image);
```

Calculate the ratio

1. If the image width and height are both less than 200 we can continue with the same size.
2. if any one or both of width and
      height is greater than 200 we need to calculate the new width and
      height by multiplying with the ratio 200/max(width,height), inorder
      to avoid cropping either top(if width is more) or left (if height is
      more) by maintaining aspect ratio.

`$ratio = min(200/$imageData[0],200/$imageData[1],1);`

Calculate new width and height

```
$width = (INT) round($ratio * $imageData[0]);
$height = (INT) round($ratio * $imageData[1]);
```

So the resize code becomes as follows

```
imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,$imageData[0], $imageData[1])
```

If the ratio is 1 there is no problem but if the ratio is less than 1, We get either less width/height image than required i.e 200*200.

For this you can create a new transparent png or white (200*200) jpg and place the newly generated image apprioriately i.e if height is less place it vertically centered or if the width is less place it horizontally centered and save that file.

This can be done using a similar method posted in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Source : http://xlab.co.in/resize-an-image-without-crop-using-php/